# Electrical workaround for wiring a smart switch

Tags: wiring, light

There's the following setup in my bedroom:

[image: before]

I need to wire the WiFi Switch in the setup above so I made the following workaround:

[image: after]

Basically I dimissed Light Bulb 2 in order to get the power line to the WiFi Switch and I reversed the Lin and N (I assume that the [switch](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-touch.html) links Lin and Lout when activated).

Questions:

1. Does this setup pose any risks?
2. Is there a better alternative to this workaround? (I can't change how the wires are set up inside the walls; ideally I would get the N in the ceiling and the L in the wall).

Comment: Why did the unmodified system use switched neutrals? That seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Can you post photos of the boxes involved?

Comment: @Transistor: I guess that's just how the wiring was done (it's an old building).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Which boxes? [This is the switch](https://www.gearbest.com/access-control/pp_1588267.html) and here's how it looks [from behind](https://imgur.com/a/9noqTUg).

Comment: @Razvan -- the places where the switch and lights are wired to the mains, basically (some places use boxes, others wiring roses)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: This is how [the switch box](https://imgur.com/a/IJhHw7f) looks like (there's the old non-smart switch in the picture). I don't have a picture with the lights wiring at the moment, but they are wired just like in the second diagram.

Comment: We need to see more into the back of the switch box.  They don't make blue-blue cable, so clearly, there's another cable there.  If the switch is actually switching neutral, that is a code violation, and also, it is mechanically incompatible with how smart switches work, so that existing defect would first have to be corrected.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think there's any color convention here (btw, I'm living in Romania, so I'm not sure if we're sharing the same standard). Here are the [detailed pictures of the switch](https://imgur.com/a/N1y5OVF). Yes, I'm switching neutral (that can be seen in the second diagram).

Comment: There is *now* (blue=neutral brown=hot1 black=hot2) but regardless, your building's communist heritage has given you a bonus, your wires are in conduit.  You can open up boxes on both ends of the in-wall piping run and fit any wire you need.